# Will arm compiler 6 work for cross Compilation of software for ARM board iMx6 cortex A9?

Tags: arm, embedded

I am new to ARM board developement. I recently bought imx6 nxp make arm **cortex A9** cpu. It already comes with scatter file (linker and description file) and startup code and other Board support packages.

I have latest version of ARM DS which comes with **ARM compiler 6**, Will it work or do i have to get **ARM compiler 5** as it supports arm v7 , since **A9** is also v7.

Also are there any other libraries or files required for compilation or just these will be enough?

Comment: Generally all compilers strive to be backwards compatible.  The v6 compiler will support a super-set of v5 CPUs.  An issue is more likely to come for compiler deprecated feature that is in the code base, versus an issue related to the target CPU.  In fact, I would put the ratio at near 1000 to one.  In more plain language, are the scatter files, etc that you rely on, broken by the compiler upgrade.  It will have next to nothing to do with the CPU you use, if it was supported in a prior version.

Comment: @artlessnoise ... although it should be noted that v6 is based in LLVM/clang, while v5 is ARM proprietary armcc, so not really the same compiler at all.  In the end though, it is an RTFM question surely?

Comment: @Clifford  Point taken, but given that, it is way more likely that the linker from V5 will not be the same.  And for certain there will be parser differences between LLVM and armcc that will cause more of an issue.  The CPU support  would be a tip of the iceberg, which was my main point.  And yet, the answer is from the manual... but that answer is not really important.

Comment: @artlessnoise. Indeed - we are in complete agreement.  Although both use the same armlink linker as it happens.  ARM publish a migration guide detailing the differences: https://documentation-service.arm.com/static/5e7b66127158f500bd5bd32d?token=

Answer (score 3):

The ARM documentation (forgive me, stackexchange, for linking an external site) shows Arm Compiler 6 supports the A9 in bare metal mode:

https://developer.arm.com/documentation/100748/0620/Getting-Started/Architectures-supported-by-Arm-Compiler-for-Embedded-6

> Arm Compiler for Embedded supports the following architectures:
>
> - Armv9-A.
> - Armv8-A and all update releases, for bare-metal targets.
> - Armv8-R.
> - Armv8-M.
> - Armv7-A for bare-metal targets.
> - Armv7-R.
> - Armv7-M.
> - Armv6-M.

Comment: Linking externally for reference/citation is fine (in fact good practice).  Posting only a link with no actual answer would be an issue.